# Problems with use Jsoup library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying make a project using Jsoup library.
I imported the library using maven.
My problem is when I have start to code using Jsoup classes and methods, eclipse don't show me anything available to import and to use from "org.jsoup"

I've already used Maven update project but my project has all dependencies placed right.

Someone got this problem too and could help me?

That is my current pom.xml on dependencies section:

```
<build>
    <finalName>crawler-api</finalName>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
          <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

and my project libraries screenshot:
[project libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNHZt.png)

Comment: Please paste relevant sections from `pom.xml` and `.classpath`

Comment: Done @lance-java can you tell me if I did something wrong?

Comment: I asked for `pom.xml` AND `.classpath`, you only provided `pom.xml`

Comment: Also, why is jsoup `<scope>provided</scope>`? Is your container providing this dependency?

Comment: Hi @lance-java I think you not notice, but I included a link to a screenshot at the final of my post after pom.xml.

Comment: I don't think so. I've learned that If you set provided in scope tag the library still available to you without include anything inside your application server. So the library will be available inside your artifact. Or is that incorrect?

Comment: @lance-java apparently it's a bug from jsoup. So I'll have to add by hand the jars. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well. After some struggles I will leave some details about what I did to solve my problem.

Unfortunately for some reason if you try add Jsoup library from maven repository I can get the classes and methods from the api.
I found some comments on github from people who said that the only solution for that is including the jars into your project. What sounds a bit old fashion.

Well. Let's get started.

First, create a folder called lib into src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ and have included the jsoup .jar that I have downloaded from the official web site.
After that I've added into pom.xml on dependencies section the follow child tag.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jsoup-1.11.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

So when I've started code my app using the classes and methods from the api everything seems available when I called. And after that when I built my artifact using maven the dependencies has been available inside my artifact.

I really hope this could help someone. And I hope that the developers of Jsoup somehow fix that.